# Is there any Lie algebra structure on the sheaf of sections of adjoint bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be an irreducible smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. 
Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. 
Let $p : E_G \longrightarrow X$ be a holomorphic principal $G$-bundle on $X$. Let $ad(E_G) = E_G \times^G \mathfrak{g}$ be the adjoint vector bundle of $E_G$ associated to the adjoint representation $ad : G \longrightarrow End(\mathfrak{g})$ of $G$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The fibers of $ad(E_G)$ are $\mathbb{C}$-linearly isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$. 
Consider $ad(E_G)$ as a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on $X$.

**Question:** Is there any $\mathcal{O}_X$-bilinear homomorphism 
$[,] : ad(E_G)\times ad(E_G) \to ad(E_G)$ giving a Lie algebra structure on the sheaf $ad(E_G)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A principal $G$-bundle gives a **monoidal** functor from the category of representations of $G$ to the category of vector bundles. In particular, it takes the morphism
$$
[-,-] \colon \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}
$$
of $G$-representations (for the adjoint action) to a morphism of vector bundles
$$
[-,-] \colon ad(E_G) \otimes ad(E_G) \to ad(E_G).
$$
By functoriality, it is skew-symmetric and satisfies the Jacobi identity, hence provides the sheaf $ad(E_G)$ with a Lie algebra structure.

Comment: Can you please show how the Jacobi identity follows from functoriality?

Comment: @VítTuček: The Jacobian identity says that the sum of three maps $ad(E_G) \otimes ad(E_G) \otimes ad(E_G) \to ad(E_G)$ vanishes. These maps come from three maps $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$. The sum of the latter maps is zero, hence so is the sum of the former maps.

Comment: So monoidal functors are automatically additive?

Comment: No, certainly not. You need additivity and the functor also needs to be symmetric monoidal, not just monoidal, to preserve skew-symmetry and the Jacobi identity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It boils down to natural isomorphism $ad(E_G) \otimes ad(E_G) \simeq E_G \times^G (\mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g})$ which allows you to compose tensor product of sections with the bracket on $\mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g}$.